# Audio tag attribute issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create audio tag with bunch of attributes.

I have

```
var audioPlayer=document.createElement('audio');
var audioSource=document.createElement('source');

     audioSource.type="audio/mp3";

     audioPlayer.controls="controls";
     audioPlayer.autoplay="autoplay";    

$('div').append(audioPlayer);
```

My html become:

in Chrome

```
<audio controls autoplay id='test', class='classname'>

</audio>
```

in FF

```
<audio controls='' autoplay='' id='test', class='classname'>

</audio>
```

What should i do to create these in javascript? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`controls` and `autoplay` are boolean values, meaning just the presence of the attribute is enough - its value makes no difference.

Personally I like to set `audioPlayer.controls = true;` since it's boolean.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Is the element showing with controls like it should be? Is it autplaying like it should?

Comment: i got it now. turns out the control and autoplay are not the issue of my bug. it was mime type in server..